# Cordova splash screen visible while navigation in multipage Android app

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen

We have a Multipage Cordova App for Android and iOS platform.

We have installed a few plugins like:

- cordova-plugin-network-information 0.2.15
- cordova-plugin-splashscreen - 2.1.1
- cordova-plugin-geolocation  0.3.12
- cordova-plugin-whitelist  1.1.1
- cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.0.2

All plug-ins are working fine on iOS platform. But, in Android cordova-plugin-splashscreen behaviour different. When we open the App, the splash screen is visible that is what the expected behaviour of that plug-in is.

But, when we navigate from one page to other there is a little delay in transition. During this transition the Splash screen is visible and this is very weird behaviour. Can anyone please help in this issue?

**Technology stack:**

- Cordova 4.2.0
- Installed Platform Android 4.0.2
- iOS 8.2
- Android 5.1.1
- API 22 Java 1.7 + Spring  for REST API

Answer (score 0):

A splash-screen appears while your app is loading i.e. it depends on the complexity of the code. If it's running well on your iOS platform but showing up on Android platform - well the device that you are using to test has a slower performance rate?
If you are running on simulators, and not devices, then switch over to considering testing on devices.

UPDATE 1: Make sure you have this in your config.xml -

```
<param name="onload" value="true" />
```

Comment: Lohith Krishna thanks for the reply, it is visible everywhere on Device and simulators. The problem is not first time, but after the app is loaded it should not be visible during navigation between pages. We have tried hiding the Splash screen using the navigator object as well but no luck.

Comment: @PareshLagdhir - can you share the technical stack details of your project? JSFramework(if any), Android version, iOS version etc.? 
Have you tried placing a "Loader" between screen navigation? Check if the loader is replacing the splash screen. After placing a loader, if still your splash screen is appearing, somewhere - something is overriding your code and the splash screen is appearing on top.

Comment: I have updated original question with required information. Yes, we are using loader and the loader is working fine. The problem with us is we have multi page application. So, I think when there is nothing to display while navigate from one page to other "The splash screen" appears.

Comment: @PareshLagdhir - seems to be pretty straight forward..no complexity involved. Is this using jquerymobile?

Comment: PareshLagdhir - I have a multi page project created - with a replica of your tech stack, but I don't see any issue so far. Also, Splash is something that appears only on the app's first time load - Please see update in my answer.